# Checking if the title of a page includes some string in Cucumber and Watir

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir and Cucumber for testing and I want to check if the title of a page includes some given string.

I tried with:

```
    Then(/^the title page should include (.*)$/) do |title|
     @browser.title.include?title
     @browser.close
    end
```

but doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I found the answer. 1. gem install rspec-expectations.
2.in .rb file add require "rspec/expectations"
3. expect(@browser.title).to include(title)

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer choose it as the answer to this question pls.  It closes this off and it'll be easier to read the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
 1. gem install rspec-expectations. 
 2. in .rb file add require "rspec/expectations" 
 3. expect(@browser.title).to include(title)